Tag [admission] is seemingly a synonym for [graduate-admissions]. Is this good?
I was looking for a tag admission, for a question which is perhaps related to the subject.  Stack Exchange suggested the tag graduate-admissions instead.  In fine print at the bottom, it said: "also: admission".  I think this means that admission is a synonym of graduate-admissions.
My question may be related to undergraduate admissions, but is unrelated to graduate admissions.
Might it make sense to either:

A.)  de-synonymize the two tags, or
B.)  rename graduate-admissions to admission, or
C.)  create a new tag undergraduate-admissions?


As stated in our help center, undergraduate admissions are off topic. The reason is that undergraduate admissions are typically not handled by academics or academic-adjacent folks, but rather by dedicated university staff ("admissions officers"). Thus, we have no real expertise to offer. Personally, I'm surprised that there isn't a "pre-college" stack to fill this need, but there isn't.
This being the case, I think the status quo makes sense.
It's ultimately up to the voters, but your question might be okay because it "could equally apply" to post-graduate students. For example, medical or law students probably face the same policy that you're asking about. But I do recommend removing the word "undergrad" from your title.

There might not be a Stack Exchange for this purpose, but there are plenty of sub-Reddits, Facebook groups, and other communities.  You could check Area 51.  Perhaps a pre-college Stack Exchange might already have been proposed, and perhaps you could upvote the proposal if it has.

Yes, no shortage of places to ask such questions on the internet. I have no personal interest in starting a "pre-college" stack, I'm just noting that (a) there is clearly some demand for it, based on the number of "what are my odds?" posts that slip through our nets, and (b) there is currently nowhere on SE where such posts would be on-topic. Maybe someday.

A former SE community manager had their next job at "College Confidential" in the same role (they've since moved on). I've sometimes pointed people interested in undergrad admissions there. Though I'll warn that the undergrad admissions community is an absolute zoo, a lot of unstable parents out there helicoptering. I think that's one reason it would never be a good fit for SE.
